# Why is it required to assign a function on the client of a Signalr jquery client?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am using Signalr 2.2.0. On the  jquery.signalR client, I have to put a "void" function in order for the event OnDisconnected to be called from the client successfully.

Ex.

```js
hubNameHub.client.void = function() {};

MyNamespace.Hub = connection.hub.start();
MyNamespace.Hub.done(function() {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK that's just a current limitation of SignalR, which might even go away in future versions. You need at least one client side event handler in order to have server side connection events working. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655104/720780) and [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection).

Comment: Thank you! I did not see the note on the Signalr page.